# Android text selection text color is off

Tags: android, android-theme, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar whose text color should be white. However, I want my theme to be the Light theme.

Here's how I currently accomplish that:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:theme="@style/ActionBar"/>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
</style>
```

However, when I select text, the toolbar looks really weird:

[image]

As you can see, the topmost toolbar's color is white when it should be black.

So here's my question: How can I make the topmost Text selection toolbar look acceptable? Either the text color needs to change, or the background color needs to change. Either works for me.

I have tried this code:

styles.xml

```
<item name="actionModeStyle">@android:style/Theme.Black</item>
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@android:color/black</item>
```

and this code:

styles.xml

```
<item name="actionModeStyle">@style/textSelection</item>
<style name="textSelection">
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
</style>
```

but neither works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may have already solved this by now, but I got this working by creating a theme (in `themes.xml`) and setting the `actionModeBackground`, similar to what you were doing in your toolbar style.

```
<style name="LightTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <!-- toolbar -->
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/themeActionMode_light</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Then, once the activity launches, I set the theme:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.setTheme(R.style.LightTheme)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.foo);
    }
}
```